# Linux vs. Windows File.delete()

Tags: java, delete-file, platform-specific

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding how Windows handles files compared to Linux. I'm trying to remove an entry in a file that I'm using as a "database" (it's just a regular file). Java unfortunately offers no method for doing this, so I have to copy all the entries except the one I want to delete into a temporary file, delete the old database, create a new empty database file, copy the contents of the temporary file into the new database file, and finish off by deleting the temporary.

Here's the code for my function:

```
private void removeSelectedItem(String entryToRemove) {

    //original database file
    File database = new File("catalog");

    //all entries except selected will be written here first
    File temp = new File("temp");

    boolean endOfFileFlag = false;
    String line = "";

    try {

        //used for reading original database file
        BufferedReader databaseReader =
            new BufferedReader(new FileReader(database));

        //used for writing to newly-created temp file
        BufferedWriter tempWriter =
            new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(temp, true));

        /*
         * Read original database line by line and test to see if the line
         * has the course prefix and id. If it does, it won't be written to
         * the temp file.
         */
        while (endOfFileFlag == false) {

            line = databaseReader.readLine();

            /*
             * This code is ugly. If possible, this check needs to be
             * made in the conditions of the while loop.
             */
            if (line == null) {

                endOfFileFlag = true;
                break;

            }

            //tests to see if the line is to be removed
            if ( !line.contains(entryToRemove))
                tempWriter.write(line + "\r\n");

        }

        endOfFileFlag = false; //reset this for the next loop
        databaseReader.close(); //database will be deleted
        tempWriter.close(); //temp file is written
        database.delete(); //delete this to create a new updated one below

        database.createNewFile();

        //writes to the new database
        BufferedWriter databaseWriter =
                new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(database, true));

        //reads from the temp file
        BufferedReader tempReader =
            new BufferedReader(new FileReader(temp));

        //read temp line by line and add each line to a new catalog file
        while (endOfFileFlag == false) {

            line = tempReader.readLine();

            /*
             * This code is ugly. If possible, this check needs to be made
             * in the conditions of the while loop. Attempts thus far have
             */
            if(line == null){

                endOfFileFlag = true;
                break;

            }

            databaseWriter.write(line + "\r\n");

        }

        tempReader.close(); //temp will be deleted
        databaseWriter.close(); //new database has been written
        temp.delete(); //temp file no longer needed

        setUpInfo(); //update the lists with the new catalog info

    }catch(IOException e){

        System.out.println("removeSelectedItem()");
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

}
```

This code (for the exception of the "\r\n," which in Linux is only "\n") executes perfectly under Linux, but in Windows I found that when I would activate the event handler for removing an entry, the program would only add extra entries. After debugging I found that the call to `database.delete()` isn't actually deleting the database file, while the call to `temp.delete()` is deleting the temporary file (like it's supposed to). I found this odd so I checked the permissions of the file and they are set to "read/write." I tried the following fix I found on the internet:

```
endOfFileFlag = false; //reset this for the next loop
databaseReader.close(); //database will be deleted
tempWriter.close(); //temp file is written
database.delete(); //delete this to create a new updated one below
//new code
database = null;
System.gc();
```

But it didn't work. I can't think of anything else that could be happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, No OS supports deleting part of a file (except the end)

You can't delete a file you have open so you have to be sure you closed it everywhere, but you can create a temporary file and rename it as the original. (No need to copy it back)

Here is how I might write it

```
public static void removeLine(String filename, String line) {
    File from = new File(filename);
    File tmp = new File(filename + ".tmp");
    PrintWriter pw = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        pw = new PrintWriter(tmp);
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(from));
        boolean found = false;
        for (String line2; (line2 = br.readLine()) != null; )
            if (line2.equals(line))
                found = true;
            else
                pw.println(line2);
        pw.close();
        br.close();
        if (found) {
            from.delete();
            tmp.renameTo(from);
        } else {
            tmp.delete();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // log error.
        try { if (br != null) br.close(); } catch (IOException ignored) { }
        if (pw != null) pw.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I know no OS supports deleting data from in the middle of the file. My confusion is in why Windows won't delete the file but Linux will. Linux doesn't let me delete a file I have a `Reader` or `Writer` attached to. I have to admit I didn't know you could just rename the file (that's a lack of research on my part and I was wishing I could because it makes the algorithm more efficient), but the code still doesn't change the fact that the file won't delete.

Comment: Windows is much more eager to lock files and prevent you from performing operations on them.  Windows XP can prevent you from deleting a file, you ever had open which is annoying to say the least.

Comment: Yeah I think it has something to do with that. By the way, I added your suggestion to rename the temp file instead of copying over all the temp's contents to a new database file with my Linux build, and it worked perfectly, so thank you for that.

Answer (score 2):

As for your `\r\n` vs `\n` issue, use `System.getProperty("line.separator")` (or Java 7's `System.lineSeparator()`) to determine your end of line character sequence.

Make sure you have closed the file everywhere. Try using the [`Path`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) class to read the file. I don't know why you can't delete it currently, but maybe this will solve the problem.

Also, you should use the following structure for your `while` loop (to avoid using `break`):

```
while (endOfFileFlag == false) {

    line = databaseReader.readLine();

    if (line == null)
        endOfFileFlag = true;
    else if ( !line.contains(entryToRemove))
        tempWriter.write(line + "\r\n");

}
```

Comment: @Hugo, Did you also change your second `if` statement to `if else`?

Comment: Oh wow. That was my bad. I was kinda side-tracked when I was first answering so both my answers were incomplete. Is there any reason why I shouldn't be using break though? And also, it seems like using `Path` to create the `BufferedReader` instead of just using a normal file would give me the same issue even with a more complicated implementation, because the `BufferedReader` is still causing the file to be locked. I can't test this out right now, but can anybody else weigh in on this?

Comment: Sorry for double posting, but thanks for your answer because it did help me as well. I can only mark one of them as the accepted answer.

Comment: @Hugo, using `break` is considered sloppy because it promotes improper/inefficient use of sentinel values in loops. They is nothing "wrong" with using `break`, but it can lead to bad habits, causing you to use `break` when you shouldn't.